# Mark Android Sms Conversation as read. Sql query getting executed again and again.(Error)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am trying to mark all messages in a android chat thread as read. I am using following code which I copied from AOSP project but I my app goes into ANR and I keep getting following message in logs.

```
ContentValues sReadContentValues = new ContentValues(2);
sReadContentValues.put("read", 1);
sReadContentValues.put("seen", 1);
private static final String UNREAD_SELECTION = "(read=0 OR seen=0)";
context.getContentResolver().update(threadUri, sReadContentValues, UNREAD_SELECTION, null);
```

Log message repeating in loop

```
SQLiteConnectionPool:   executeForChangedRowCount started 152577ms ago - running, sql="UPDATE sms SET read=?,seen=? WHERE (read=0 OR seen=0) AND thread_id=1464"
```

I have been trying to fixed this issue since ours but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but I found it looking for how to properly utilize the ContentValue type and it answered my question, so I will answer it...

**Looping Log Message:**
You have only posted a small portion of your code, so my best guess is that you are executing this update every time you select a message - inside your code loop. If that *is* the case, since you are attempting to update the entire thread in one execution, it would be logical to move this section of code into its own method (assuming it isn't already) and call it only once, AFTER you have received all of the desired messages and you have exited the loop.

**App Entering [ANR](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html):**
Though the Log message you have posted reads "(read=0 OR seen=0) AND thread_id=1464", your code only reflects "(read=0 OR seen=0)" in your Where Clause - this would obviously cause some frustration due to the fact that you would be attempting to update every message in every message thread.

While a method attempting to update all existing threads *would* be time-consuming for the processor, if you also execute this within the loop (as your Log message implies), then it makes a lot of sense that you would receive an ANR, even if you are including the requirement that it only run for a single thread_id...

**Solution:**
Feel free to correct me, but making some logical assumptions, I believe this is your solution:

```
public void mainMethod()
{
    String threadId = "1464";
    Cursor cursor = getSomeMessages(threadId);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // ... Do something with the message
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }

    updateMessagesToReadAndSeen(threadId);
}

private void updateMessagesToReadAndSeen(String threadId) {
    if (threadId != null && !threadId.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues sReadContentValues = new ContentValues(2);
        sReadContentValues.put("read", 1);
        sReadContentValues.put("seen", 1);
        String UNREAD_SELECTION = "(read=0 OR seen=0) AND thread_id=" + threadId;
        context.getContentResolver().update(threadUri, sReadContentValues, UNREAD_SELECTION, null);
    }
}
```

I guess if I had to make some suggestions for "scope-friendly changes" it would be to break this apart into more flexible methods. eg...

```
private void UpdateContent(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String _where, String[] args) {
    _context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, _where, args);
}
```

...

```
private static String UNREAD_UNSEEN_THREADID = "(read=0 OR seen=0) AND thread_id=";

private void updateMessagesReadAndSeen(String threadId, int setRead, int setSeen) {
    if (threadId != null && !threadId.isEmpty()) {
        ContentValues sReadContentValues = new ContentValues(2);
        sReadContentValues.put("read", setRead);
        sReadContentValues.put("seen", setSeen);

        UNREAD_UNSEEN_THREADID +=  threadId;
        UpdateContent(threadUri, sReadContentValues, UNREAD_UNSEEN_THREADID, null);
    }
}
```

I could go on forever, but this would allow a lot more flexibility moving forward as you develop new features for your product. Good luck!